# How to add a (Swift4) init to the Decodable protocol

Tags: json, init, swift4, codable, decodable

I am trying to create a [Codable extension](https://github.com/evermeer/Stuff#codable) that is capable of initialising a Decodable (Swift 4) object with only a json string. So what Should work is:

```
struct MyObject: Decodable {
   var title: String?
}

let myObject = MyObject(json: "{\"title\":\"The title\"}")
```

I think this means that I should create an init that calls the self.init with a Decoder. Here is the code that I came up with:

```
public init?(json: String) throws {
    guard let decoder: Decoder = GetDecoder.decode(json: json)?.decoder else { return }
    try self.init(from: decoder) // Who what should we do to get it so that we can call this?
}
```

That code is capable of getting the decoder, but I get a compiler error on calling the init. The error that I get is:

> 'self' used before self.init call

Does this mean that there is no way to add an init to the Decodable protocol?

For the complete source code see the [codable extension on github](https://github.com/evermeer/Stuff/blob/master/Source/Codable/Codable.swift#L86)

**update:**
After debugging the solution below from @appzYourLive I found out that I had a conflict with the `init(json:` initialisers on Decodable and Array. I just published a new version of the extension to GitHub. I also added the solution as a new answer to this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> A possible workaround

### DecodableFromString

A possible solution is defining another protocol

```
protocol DecodableFromString: Decodable { }
```

with its own initializer

```
extension DecodableFromString {
    init?(from json: String) throws {
        guard let data = try json.data(using: .utf8) else { return nil }
        guard let value = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Self.self, from: data) else { return nil }
        self = value
    }
}
```

### Conforming to DecodableFromString

Now you need to conform your type to `DecodableFromString`

```
struct Person:Codable, DecodableFromString {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
}
```

### Result

And finally given a JSON

```
let json =  """
            {
            "firstName": "Luke",
            "lastName": "Skywalker"
            }
            """
```

you can build your value

```
if let luke = try? Person(from: json) {
    print(luke)
}
```

> Person(firstName: "Luke", lastName: "Skywalker")

Comment: ha!... At first I was puzzled why this worked but why I could not add that extension to the Decodable protocol itself. It turns out that my init(json on the Decodable protocol conflicted with the one on the Array protocol. I think I have it now working as an extension to Decodable.. I will play around with it some more and let you know the results...

Comment: Since your answer caused me to think about my implementation and made me create the fix, I think you deserve the 50 points. I marked my own answer as the correct one since that is what I ended up with.

Answer (score 3):

This is what can be done:

```
extension Decodable {

    init?(jsonString: String) throws {
        guard let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8) else { return nil }
        self = try JSONDecoder().decode(Self.self, from: jsonData)
    }

}
```

See: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5356

**[UPD]**  Problem fixed in XCode 9 beta 3 (see the above link for details).

Comment: This does not work on my Xcode 9: `error: incorrect argument label in call (have 'jsonString:', expected 'from:')`

Comment: You are right, this does work if the Type is explicitly declared conform do `Decodable` (instead of `Codable`). Good answer!

Comment: That's strange.. Codable is just a typeAlias for DeCodable and Encodable. It's specified like this: 'public typealias Codable = Decodable & Encodable' In my unit test (see GitHub) It works with Codable. It's only that I use init without the question mark. So instead of returning nil I throw an error.

Comment: hmm... Who shall I give the 50 points... I was able to solve my problem after  the answer of @appzYourLife but your answer is better. But my final solution is using a non failable initialiser to work around the swift bug...

Answer (score -1):

My original problem was caused by these 2 reasons:

- A conflict between an init with an identical signature that I added as an
  extension to Array which is also Codable when its inner objects are
  Codable.
- A swift compiler bug that causes a problem when you use a failable
  initialiser. See https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5356

So since there is an issue with using a failable initialiser I ended up with:

```
public extension Decodable {
    init(json: String) throws {
        guard let data = json.data(using: .utf8) else { throw CodingError.RuntimeError("cannot create data from string") }
        try self.init(data: data, keyPath: keyPath)
    }

    init(data: Data) throws {
        self = try JSONDecoder().decode(Self.self, from: data)
    }
}

enum CodingError : Error {
    case RuntimeError(String)
}
```

I also made a variation where you kan use a keyPath to jump to a certain section:

```
public extension Decodable {
    init(json: String, keyPath: String? = nil) throws {
        guard let data = json.data(using: .utf8) else { throw CodingError.RuntimeError("cannot create data from string") }
        try self.init(data: data, keyPath: keyPath)
    }

    init(data: Data, keyPath: String? = nil) throws {
        if let keyPath = keyPath {
            let topLevel = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)
            guard let nestedJson = (topLevel as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: keyPath) else { throw CodingError.RuntimeError("Cannot decode data to object")  }
            let nestedData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: nestedJson)
            self = try JSONDecoder().decode(Self.self, from: nestedData)
            return
        }
        self = try JSONDecoder().decode(Self.self, from: data)
    }
}
```

You can find the complete code of my Decodable and Encodable extensions below. It's also in my GitHub subspec. With this extension you can use code like:

```
struct YourCodableObject : Codable {
    var naam: String?
    var id: Int?
}

let json = yourEncodableObjectInstance.toJsonString()
let data = yourEncodableObjectInstance.toJsonData()
let newObject = try? YourCodableObject(json: json)
let newObject2 = try? YourCodableObject(data: data)
let objectArray = try? [YourCodableObject](json: json)
let objectArray2 = try? [YourCodableObject](data: data)
let newJson = objectArray.toJsonString()
let innerObject = try? TestCodable(json: "{\"user\":{\"id\":1,\"naam\":\"Edwin\"}}", keyPath: "user")
try initialObject.saveToDocuments("myFile.dat")
let readObject = try? TestCodable(fileNameInDocuments: "myFile.dat")
try objectArray.saveToDocuments("myFile2.dat")
let objectArray3 = try? [TestCodable](fileNameInDocuments: "myFile2.dat")
```

And here are the 2 extensions:

```
//
//  Codable.swift
//  Stuff
//
//  Created by Edwin Vermeer on 28/06/2017.
//  Copyright © 2017 EVICT BV. All rights reserved.
//

enum CodingError : Error {
    case RuntimeError(String)
}

public extension Encodable {
    /**
     Convert this object to json data

     - parameter outputFormatting: The formatting of the output JSON data (compact or pritty printed)
     - parameter dateEncodinStrategy: how do you want to format the date
     - parameter dataEncodingStrategy: what kind of encoding. base64 is the default

     - returns: The json data
     */
    public func toJsonData(outputFormatting: JSONEncoder.OutputFormatting = .compact, dateEncodingStrategy: JSONEncoder.DateEncodingStrategy = .deferredToDate, dataEncodingStrategy: JSONEncoder.DataEncodingStrategy = .base64Encode) -> Data? {
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        encoder.outputFormatting = outputFormatting
        encoder.dateEncodingStrategy = dateEncodingStrategy
        encoder.dataEncodingStrategy = dataEncodingStrategy
        return try? encoder.encode(self)
    }

    /**
     Convert this object to a json string

     - parameter outputFormatting: The formatting of the output JSON data (compact or pritty printed)
     - parameter dateEncodinStrategy: how do you want to format the date
     - parameter dataEncodingStrategy: what kind of encoding. base64 is the default

     - returns: The json string
     */
    public func toJsonString(outputFormatting: JSONEncoder.OutputFormatting = .compact, dateEncodingStrategy: JSONEncoder.DateEncodingStrategy = .deferredToDate, dataEncodingStrategy: JSONEncoder.DataEncodingStrategy = .base64Encode) -> String? {
        let data = self.toJsonData(outputFormatting: outputFormatting, dateEncodingStrategy: dateEncodingStrategy, dataEncodingStrategy: dataEncodingStrategy)
        return data == nil ? nil : String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)
    }


    /**
     Save this object to a file in the temp directory

     - parameter fileName: The filename

     - returns: Nothing
     */
    public func saveTo(_ fileURL: URL) throws {
        guard let data = self.toJsonData() else { throw CodingError.RuntimeError("cannot create data from object")}
        try data.write(to: fileURL, options: .atomic)
    }


    /**
     Save this object to a file in the temp directory

     - parameter fileName: The filename

     - returns: Nothing
     */
    public func saveToTemp(_ fileName: String) throws {
        let fileURL = try FileManager.default.url(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false).appendingPathComponent(fileName)
        try self.saveTo(fileURL)
    }



    #if os(tvOS)
    // Save to documents folder is not supported on tvOS
    #else
    /**
     Save this object to a file in the documents directory

     - parameter fileName: The filename

     - returns: true if successfull
     */
    public func saveToDocuments(_ fileName: String) throws {
        let fileURL = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false).appendingPathComponent(fileName)
        try self.saveTo(fileURL)
    }
    #endif
}

public extension Decodable {
    /**
     Create an instance of this type from a json string

     - parameter json: The json string
     - parameter keyPath: for if you want something else than the root object
     */
    init(json: String, keyPath: String? = nil) throws {
        guard let data = json.data(using: .utf8) else { throw CodingError.RuntimeError("cannot create data from string") }
        try self.init(data: data, keyPath: keyPath)
    }

    /**
     Create an instance of this type from a json string

     - parameter data: The json data
     - parameter keyPath: for if you want something else than the root object
     */
    init(data: Data, keyPath: String? = nil) throws {
        if let keyPath = keyPath {
            let topLevel = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)
            guard let nestedJson = (topLevel as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: keyPath) else { throw CodingError.RuntimeError("Cannot decode data to object")  }
            let nestedData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: nestedJson)
            let value = try JSONDecoder().decode(Self.self, from: nestedData)
            self = value
            return
        }
        self = try JSONDecoder().decode(Self.self, from: data)
    }

    /**
     Initialize this object from an archived file from an URL

     - parameter fileNameInTemp: The filename
     */
    public init(fileURL: URL) throws {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
        try self.init(data: data)
    }

    /**
     Initialize this object from an archived file from the temp directory

     - parameter fileNameInTemp: The filename
     */
    public init(fileNameInTemp: String) throws {
        let fileURL = try FileManager.default.url(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false).appendingPathComponent(fileNameInTemp)
        try self.init(fileURL: fileURL)
    }

    /**
     Initialize this object from an archived file from the documents directory

     - parameter fileNameInDocuments: The filename
     */
    public init(fileNameInDocuments: String) throws {
        let fileURL = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false).appendingPathComponent(fileNameInDocuments)
        try self.init(fileURL: fileURL)
    }
}
```